# Gentoo: how do I get an IP assigned to the network interface?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, gentoo

I'm trying to install Gentoo from the LiveCD (just for fun as well as for getting better understanding what's going on under the Linux's hood) on my notebook. 
I've faced an issue which is not described in manuals quite well.
When I'm trying to ping anything:

```
livecd~# ping 8.8.8.8
```

I'm getting this:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

There are three interfaces presented: **lo**, **enp30s0** and **wlp4s0**. None of them has IP assigned.
As the notebook should connect to the network using wi-fi, I suppose the default interface is **wlp4s0**.
I'm trying to bring it up:

```
livecd~# ip link set wlp4s0 up
```

but with no luck, it still has state DOWN.

UPDATE:

Anyway, other devices (notebook, phone, tablet) have perfect wifi connection.

```
  livecd~# uname -a
  Linux livecd 3.18.12-gentoo #1 SMP Thu Jun 4 06:18:47 UTC 2015 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 370 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

  livecd~# lspci -v -nn | grep Network -A1 
  04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 [Kilmer Peak] [8086:0089] (rev 5f) 
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 2x2 AGN [8086:1311]
```

Comment: Did you follow the section on https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Networking/Wireless setup wireless (also the /etc/conf.d/net)?

Comment: If you're on DHCP, try `net-setup wlp4s0`.  Read the Handbook as @HidekiAI recommends, and also read the motd after logging in, which states about halfway down:  If you need to setup network devices, or if they're not already setup, use `net-setup`.

Comment: @HidekiAI I've tried, but got some problems there as well.
@eyoung100 after setting up with `net-setup` the problem was still actual

Comment: @hdf let's try determining whether it is your WiMax driver (i.e. you need to modprobe it) or your network in general.  Try forcing static ip via: 'ifconfig wlp4s0 <some_static_ip>; route add default gw <your_gateway_ip>' (i.e. 'ifconfig wlp4s0 10.0.10.100; route add default gw 10.0.10.1; ifconfig wlp4s0 up')

Comment: @HidekiAI Thank you! I actually gave up on wireless interface so far and used ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore your wireless interface for now, because I've seen lots of wireless APs with security that are just a complete pain to set up WPA2 on the commandline (somewhere that a GUI, even a CLI one like `wicd` shines).

Make sure an ethernet cable is plugged in, and you know it works:

```
ifconfig enp30s0 up
ethtool enp30s0
```

It should show that the interface has link, and show a speed. If it's not, then something is wrong, test via the following list: router, cable, network card, ethernet card firmware, PCI bus.

If you can reboot to another OS and confirm it works via that cable, then I'd bet on an issue with ethernet card firmware, which does sadly happen. If that is the case, can you post the output of the following commands:

```
uname -a
# The numbers at the start and in the square brackets are the most critical pieces.
lspci -v -nn |grep Ethernet -A1
# Anything that looks non-default
dmidecode -t 1,2,3
```

Comment: Ignoring wireless interface is not an option for me as my cable is not connectable to the notebook.

Comment: updated the question with the output

Comment: That's the wired network device, not the wireless one; why do you say the the cable is not connectable to the notebook? Can you please show the lspci output for the wireless network card as well? It might start with 'Network controller' instead of 'Ethernet controller'

Comment: my bad  
`livecd~# lspci -v -nn | grep Network -A1`  
`04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 [Kilmer Peak] [8086:0089] (rev 5f)
   Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 2x2 AGN [8086:1311]` 

Thank you so much

Comment: What laptop is this? I think you're going to have to install the OS using the ethernet, and then use WiFI later as it looks like a firmware issue with that wireless interface.

Comment: It's Lenovo V560.
Could you please point me why do you think so? Is your assumption based on that `lspci` output? Thanks

Comment: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-811698-view-previous.html?sid=b71fdb52c36c97e9360488c0986c21b3 and there is a lot of other results showing firmware issues on this wireless controller. Just install from ethernet and then we can work on further diagnosis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25213/discussion-between-hdf-and-robbat2).